# Playing CS GO with same Steam ID

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

I have bought CS:go , I installed it on my laptop and i do play it. But now i want to play it with my friends . Can i just copy the same steam folder from my Laptop to there laptop, and then play on LAN ? Or i have to make there different Steam Id  and then copy the steam app folder to their Steam app folder? Please help!

Comment: You can't "share" your game, steam prevents that...

Comment: You're asking for how your friends can play it without paying for it.  That's piracy, and off-topic for Arqade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to play CS:GO with friends, they'll each need to purchase their own copy.

You can be logged into Steam with the same account on multiple computers, but only one can play multiplayer at a time.  The others will be in "offline mode."

Comment: can i just play it with my friends laptop via wifi , not online ? with same ID , or different ID but same STEAMAPP folder ?

Comment: @KamalKafkaesque, you *can* copy the files to your friend's computer, but they'll need to have a different Steam account that owns the game in order to use those files.  It doesn't matter if you're playing a LAN game or an internet game as far as that's concerned.